# RegEx in bash to extract string after the first delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression

This question is not a duplicate of any other questions around here as I need a `regex` in `bash` with the `=~` matching.

Assuming I have a string like

```
string="ananas1kiwi2apple1banana2tree"
```

The `regEx` I tried was

```
[[ $string =~ .*2([[:alnum:]]{1,}) ]] && subString=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

which was supposed to match the occurrence of `2` and capture everything beyond that, which is returning me only `tree` (string after the 2nd match). My expected output is `apple1banana2tree`

I know am missing a simple construct but not exactly sure which. Am looking only for a pure `bash` `regEx` based solution. Also not any string manipulation which I know can be done by `"{string#*2}"`

Comment: Definitely a duplicate... plenty of questions out there about how to match before or after - this is a regex question, not a shell one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just match `2` and then capture everything beyond by `.*`:

```
[[ $string =~ 2(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

**Example:**

```
$ string="ananas1kiwi2apple1banana2tree"

$ [[ $string =~ 2(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
apple1banana2tree
```

---

**What's wrong with your one:**

- `.*` is greedy, it is matching upto last `2` when you use `.*2`, to have non-greediness (as `.*?` is not available in ERE) use `[^2]*2`
- Also `{1,}` is just `+`

So do:

```
[[ $string =~ [^2]*2([[:alnum:]]+) ]]
```

In any case, no need to match from the start, just do:

```
[[ $string =~ 2([[:alnum:]]+) ]]
```

Comment: Also I don't need the greedy `.*` before `2`? Just checked that `.*` before `2` isn't working. Any reason why?

Comment: @Inian Check my edits.

Comment: That's just great!

Comment: Note that it would have to be `[[ $string =~ '2(.*)' ]]` in bash-3.1. Or `re='2(.*)'; [[ $string =~ $re ]]` to be compatible with both 3.1 and 3.2+ (and zsh and ksh93). Note that bash-3.2+ and ksh93 have problems with things like `[[ x =~ [)}]+ ]]` which bash31 didn't have. You can use `shtop -s compat31` to get back to the older behaviour.